# Detect program GUI using Java

Tags: java

Is there any Java code can help to detect another program GUI part by part? 
For example, detect the size of the GUI, detect the location of the button.

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) does something similar to this but it is really not there. It will work only for browser-based apps/programs/sites. But if your target programs are browser-based, it will probably be a great tool.

For desktop programs, you might give a look to the [`createScreenCapture(Rectangle)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture-java.awt.Rectangle-) method from the [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class to get a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) with the contents of the screen, and then it is up to you to try to make sense of the image, which would not be easy. Also, you might use the `Robot` to try to juggle out windows as needed, press buttons, type text, or whatever is needed to find out what you want. All of this will be a lot of work.

Comment: If I want to capture another program GUI? Is there any other way to solve it? (For example: getting the location of the button of the other program)

Comment: @Cy9268 None that I am aware. However, I already once used the Robot-based way to search for something in the screen and click it.